# Issues with a vector<vector<string>> setup

Tags: c++, vector, text-parsing

I've created an application that parses delimited text databases of around 300k products (each with its own 70 categories) on Windows/Linux. The purpose of the application is to compare two supplied text files (one off an ftp and a local/current one) and update the local one with any changes (be it updating individual product fields, adding or removing products) as well as keep a log of these changes.

Question is this: Is there a more efficient way to do this than a 2d vector? Would perhaps a map or a vector of pairs be more efficient? Basically the comparison will be line by line, product by product, category by category. If matching entries are found on both lists, that record is then checked to confirm it's identical on both (otherwise updated), if no matching entries are found, the missing product is either removed from the local list or added to it(if missing on the local list but present on the ftp one).

All this searching up and down and the potential removal/addition of new members(order doesn't matter, so additions are pushed back at the end of the local 2d vector) seems to be causing the application performance to suffer so I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of going about this.

Note: Order is not important, double entries are not allowed, and local vector will be written back into a text file using the same delimited format. The backend php application requires this type of text/delimited format.

Thank you for your time and any advice.

Comment: Looks like a job for a database, maybe some NoSQL stuff.

Comment: calling `std::vector::reserve()` at the beginning, particularly with the main vector of vectors, with an adecuately high value, should improve the `push_back` performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). It should be a lot faster for you.